# How to follow links with hotkeys in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm a VSCode-Vim user and I was wondering if the markdown links could be followed by hotkey instead of "ctrl + click" in VSCode.
I have checked the setting list carefully but finally I failed to find any setting item to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I doubt there is a default hotkey to follow link besides the one you mentioned. You can, however, add you own -

Open Keyboard Shortcuts and search for "Open Link" (editor.action.openLink) and add your own custom shortcut here.

Cheers!

Comment: To set it to a shortcut that is already used elsewhere (e.g. F12) without having conflict, I added this "when expression" : `editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'markdown'`

Answer (score -2):

It may be irrelevant in this discussion but just for reference, the hotkey for "Go to Definition" in VS Code is F12.